# A little jquery function using .each

Tags: jquery

I thought I was being quite clever with this. I've made a little function that scales up or down an image to fit with margins within the browser window. With one image it worked great. Then I wanted to do it with several images, so I could click through the images in the same window. I tried using .each, but with little success. It scales up each image based on the dimensions of the first one only. Obviously I want each image to be scaled up depending on it's own dimensions.

js bit:

```
$(window).bind("load resize", function(){

    var ww = $(window).width();
    var wh = $(window).height();
    wh = wh-50;
    ww = ww-225;
    var wr = (ww/wh);

    $("#slides div.scale img").each(function(){
        var ow = $("img").width();
        var oh = $("img").height();
        var or = (ow/oh);
        if (wr<or) {
            $("img").css('width',ww);
            $("img").css('height','auto');
        }
        else {
            $("img").css('height',wh);
            $("img").css('width','auto');
        };
    });
});
```

html bit:

```
<div id="slides">
    <div class="slide 1 scale"><img src="portrait.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="slide 2 scale"><img src="landscape.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="slide 3 scale"><img src="square.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="slide 4 scale"><img src="portrait.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: btw... **or** might not be the best name for a variable.

Comment: @Joseph I agree with Joseph. Although it's not one of the reserved keywords, it's not the best var name, esp if people from other backgrounds have to maintain or use your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#slides div.scale img").each(function(){
    var ow = $(this).width();
    var oh = $(this).height();
    var or = (ow/oh);
    if (wr<or) {
        $(this).css('width',ww);
        $(this).css('height','auto');
    }
    else {
        $(this).css('height',wh);
        $(this).css('width','auto');
    };
});
```

Try that?

### Edit

I think this needs changed

```
function changeimage(){
    $("#slides div").css("visibility","hidden");
    $('#slidetitles span').hide();
    $("#slides div."+ns).css("visibility","visible");
    $("#slidetitles span."+ns).show();
    cs = ns;
};
```

Comment: @Jim can you put a demo together on jsbin or jsfiddle?

Comment: Here's a live demo, plus a link to a zip. http://jahyland.com/client/guest/v2d-demo/
http://jahyland.com/client/guest/v2d-demo.zip

Comment: @Jim aHA! found the problem.... display:none. This sets the width of all hidden elements to 0 resulting in false scaling. use visibility: hidden and visibility: visible instead.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the each, you need to use `$( this )` instead of `$("img")`

I've made that change for you, as well as some efficiency adjustments (all untested, though)

```
$( function()
{
    $( window ).bind( 'load resize', function()
    {
        var $win = $( this ),
            ww = $win.width() - 50,
            wh = $win.height() - 225,
            wr = ( ww / wh );

        $( '#slides div.scale img' ).each( function()
        {
            var $img = $( this ),
                ow = $img.width(),
                oh = $img.height(),
                or = ( ow / oh ),
                dimStyles;

            if( wr < or )
            {
                dimStyles = {
                    width: ww,
                    height: 'auto'
                };
            }
            else {
                dimStyles = {
                    width: 'auto',
                    height: wh
                };
            }

            $img.css( dimStyles );
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Sorry JAAulde. This doesn't seem to work for any images. Why dimStyles?

Comment: What is the error you're currently getting? I edited a couple of times as I botched the syntax--try with what's there now if you would, please. LOL, `dimStyles` is just my shortcut way of saying "dimension styles". :)  Whteher or not you use the code isn't a big deal so long as you understand to use `this` inside the each.

Comment: Yep. using $(this) is obviously the way to go. School boy error! But the code you've suggested does seem to scale my images at all. I've put a little demo here: http://jahyland.com/client/guest/v2d-demo/ and a link to download files if you like here: http://jahyland.com/client/guest/v2d-demo.zip . Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Your markup had some issues and, like I said, my syntax was untested--it was offered for reference for you to see how I'd work to improve efficiency--thus my base answer was still proper for your original question.  Here is an updated version which seems to be working: http://jaaulde.com/test_bed/v2d-demo.zip

Answer (score 1):

Your selectors in the each loop won't get each image in turn, rather an array of all img tags on the page.

in your each loop, every time you refer to an image, use $(this) instead to indicate that you mean that one particular image that is currently the subject of the loop.

eg:

```
$(this).css('height');
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the $("img") selector you're still selecting all the img tag on the page.
You should use $(this) to reference the current item that is being processed